# Evaluate the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^0 {e^x}\text{sin}\, xdx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Evaluate the improper integral $$\int_{-\infty}^0 {e^x} \sin x \, dx$$
>   justifying any non-trivial steps.

I have begun to answer this question by finding the indefinite integral,
$$\int {e^x} \sin x \, dx = \dfrac{1}2{e^x}(\sin x-\cos x)+C.$$

then gone on to say,

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow {-\infty}} \int_a^0 e^x \sin x\,dx.$$

Not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: Integrate by parts

Comment: $\sin x-\cos x$ is bounded by $\sqrt{2}$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. It follows that $$\lim_{a\to -\infty}\frac{e^a}{2}(\sin a-\cos a)=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\lim_{a\to -\infty} \int_a^0 e^x \sin x \; dx = \left.\lim_{a\to -\infty}\frac{e^x(\sin x - \cos x)}{2}\right|_a^0  $$ $$=\lim_{a\to -\infty}\frac{e^0(\sin 0 - \cos 0)}{2}-\frac{e^a(\sin a - \cos a)}{2}  =-\frac{1}{2}-0.$$

Comment: I think your limits in the second-last step are the wrong way around, the answer should be $-1/2$.

Comment: Yes, you should have $$\lim_{a\to-\infty}\left.\frac{e^x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))}{2}\right|_a^0=\frac{e^0(\sin(0)-\cos(0))}{2}-\lim_{a\to-\infty}\frac{e^a(\sin(a)-\cos(a))}{2}$$

Comment: @Joppy Yep.  I'll fix it soon.